# How do I win against a Zerg on many bases as Protoss?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, starcraft-protoss

I started thinking after seeing this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/strategies-against-zerg-when-playing-protoss), that most strategies involve aggression and better macro (true for any combination I suppose), but how do you come back if you are behind?

What if it has reached mid-game and you are 3 bases behind the Zerg player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there is a certain amount of ebb and flow you're kind of overlooking here.

Taking a base constitutes an investment, and not a light one either.  We're talking about 350+75*2+50*22(or possibly 30).  Even on 2-3 Bases this constitutes a heavy investment that could have gone to troops.  If you hit mid game and your opponent is suddenly on 5 bases and you're on 2, that means his army is going to be about 4800 minerals smaller than yours (approximately 75-90 supply for a Zerg).  At that point it doesn't really matter what he has your army size should sort of crush him.

So given that an expansion is such a heavy investment its not hard to see why many players build an army before taking a 3rd or 4th base.  Usually even early expansions are vulnerable to pressure early on.

**Every time your opponent takes a base you should consider it an opportunity.**

If they are taking 3 more bases than you have, that is 3 times the opportunity.

However, if you miss an opportunity like that, and they do get those 3 bases up and running their economy is going to start kicking in and the are going to bowl you over.  This is why so many top players go for a Macro oriented game, because its the closest thing to a `sure thing` Starcraft really has.

Comment: that is definitely a better analysis of the situation

Answer (score 1):

Look at this amazing [Huk (P) vs Min (Z) on Scrap Station](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3e-sw4v6tc) game.

Huk is definitely behind (economy-wise) but by using amazing scouting, small number of good counter units and staggering force field placements in beginning of the game, he is able to turn the tide of the battle. No disrespect to the zerg player, he tried everything in the book, but IMHO was just outclassed.

Comment: You should wait at least a few hours before answering your own question...

Comment: you watch that video and tell me if you could wait :D

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this link is really relevant.  Huk never gets behind by more than one base.  When you're talking about the effect of 1 base over the course of a game where players take 4-5 bases each the effect is diminished

Comment: IIRC, there is a point when he is on 2 bases and Min is on 4, the point where he gets attacked by lots of hydras and roaches at his natural

Comment: @Bronz look again.  Huk throws down his 3rd at the [same time](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3e-sw4v6tc#t=10m32s) Min takes his 4th.  Min is never more than a base a head.

Comment: I concede, your analysis of large investment in setting up the base is probably what happened.